How do I match types when trying to write polymorphic classes in C# or am I using the wrong pattern?
TLDR; I'm looking for a pattern that allows me to have a base class and derived classes that handle objects of various different classes but which are all derived from one interface/base class - however the List<T> notation appears to force me to override every method in every derived class.
I have a fair amount of experience with OO code in Perl, C++, Python and Java but have minimal formal OO training - fluent coding and C# are brand new to me, so I'm struggling with finding the best design patterns.
We have a server based system that presents various 'services' which allow searching of data using JSON or XML POSTs and return either JSON or XML. I'm trying to write an app that allows the user to query those services and presents the data to the user.
To make the experience as user friendly as possible I intend to use a database on the user's device (likely SQLite) as a persistent cache and when the user requests data from the service the app will query the persistent cache, put all the results into an ObservableCache (from the DynamicData / Rx library) and then make an API call to the server the response handler will then insert/update the entry in the DB and Edit the ObservableCache.
The ObservableCache will be bound to a UI element - so when the user searches they should see a very quick response (with some visual indication that the results are from a cache) and the results change when the server API responds and those results are integrated, e.g., new results are added etc. existing results show their new values.
As a lazy programmer I'd like to do minimal work to achieve this; so what I would like to do is create a class for each API I'm wrapping but for that to only contain, the search terms, the fields expected in the results and the mapping between the search terms and the result fields. All the logic governing interacting with the server and the DB should be handled in 'generic' or 'base' classes.
I'm going to include most of the code for completeness; I've gone back and forth reading various approaches and I thought I understood what I was doing.
My main challenge is that I don't seem to fully understand how to deal with type <T> notation and when to use interfaces or how to use them properly.
I've started with what I intend to use as the base class that will provide all the generic functionality.
[ZymonicFilter]
public class ZymonicFilter : IZmonicFilter
{
    // When adding properties use data annotations
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt

    private readonly SourceCache<IZymonicFilterResult, string> _items = new SourceCache<IZymonicFilterResult, string>(result => result.uid);
    public SourceCache<IZymonicFilterResult, string> results { get { return _items; } }

    protected ZymonicDbContext _dbcontext;

    public ZymonicFilter(ZymonicDbContext context)
    {
        _dbcontext = context;
    }

    // We expose the Connect() since we are interested in a stream of changes.
    // If we have more than one subscriber, and the subscribers are known, 
    // it is recommended you look into the Reactive Extension method Publish().
    public IObservable<IChangeSet<IZymonicFilterResult, string>> Connect() => _items.Connect();

    public void Search()
    {
        // Trigger the DB search to update the collection
        List<IZymonicFilterResult> results = DbSet().Where(x => WhereClause(x)).ToList();
        _items.Edit(innerCache => { innerCache.AddOrUpdate(results); });

        // TODO Trigger the API call to update the collection and DB
    }

    protected virtual DbSet<IZymonicFilterResult> DbSet()
    {
        return _dbcontext.Set<IZymonicFilterResult>();
    }

    protected virtual bool WhereClause(IZymonicFilterResult result)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public interface IZymonicFilterResult
{
    public string uid { get; set; }
}

I've then added a class based on this that has specific fields:
public class CbosFilStockLookup : ZymonicFilter
{
    public CbosFilStockLookup(ZymonicDbContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    // The report and search fields are defined by the znames of the contained fields
    // because that is what appears in the API
    [SearchField]
    public string? cbos_stock_levels_branch { get; set; }
    [SearchField]
    public int? cbos_stock_levels_branch_num { get; set; }
    [SearchField]
    public string? cbos_stock_levels_main_barcode { get; set; }
    [SearchField]
    public string? cbos_stock_levels_description { get; set; }
    [SearchField]
    public string? f_catalogue_code_sl { get; set; }

    protected override DbSet<CbosFilStockLookupResult> DbSet()
    {
        return _dbcontext.Set<CbosFilStockLookupResult>();
    }

    protected override bool WhereClause(CbosFilStockLookupResult result)
    {
        return result.cbos_stock_levels_branch_num == cbos_stock_levels_branch_num;
    }
}

public class CbosFilStockLookupResult : IZymonicFilterResult
{
    public string uid { get; set; }
    [ReportField]
    public string? cbos_stock_levels_branch { get; set; }
    [ReportField]
    public int? cbos_stock_levels_branch_num { get; set; }
    [ReportField]
    public string? cbos_stock_levels_main_barcode { get; set; }
    [ReportField]
    public string? cbos_stock_levels_description { get; set; }
    [ReportField]
    public string? f_catalogue_code_sl { get; set; }
    [ReportField]
    public string? cbos_stock_levels_colour { get; set; }
    [ReportField]
    public string? cbos_stock_levels_sizes { get; set; }
    [ReportField]
    public float? cbos_stock_levels_sum_amount { get; set; }
}

I've also added a DB context that should auto create the DbSets for me:
public class ZymonicDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // https://romiller.com/2012/03/26/dynamically-building-a-model-with-code-first/
        var entityMethod = typeof(ModelBuilder).GetMethod("Entity");

        foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            var entityTypes = assembly
              .GetTypes()
              .Where(t =>
                t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ZymonicFilterAttribute), inherit: true)
                .Any());

            foreach (var type in entityTypes)
            {
                entityMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type)
                  .Invoke(modelBuilder, new object[] { });
            }
        }
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

However, I get two errors on attempting to compile:

Error CS0508: 'CbosFilStockLookup.DbSet()': return type must be 'DbSet' to match overridden member 'ZymonicFilter.DbSet()'
Error CS0115: 'CbosFilStockLookup.WhereClause(CbosFilStockLookupResult)': no suitable method found to override [/home/amasidlover/workspace/Zymonic.NET/ZymoTestOneApp/ZymoTestOneApp.csproj]

I had thought that providing a class implemented an interface then I could use it interchangeably in the code - but clearly I can't.
EDIT 1
My aim is to end up with code that is structured roughly like the following pseudocode:
In the view model:
ViewModelConstructor() 
{
   _StockList = new MyStockList(); 
   _StockListObservableCache = _StockList.getObservableCache();
}

SearchCommand() 
{
   _StockList.SearchField1 = _SearchField1;
   _StockList.Search();
}

In the StockList class:
class MyStockList : APICachingWrapper
{
    public string SearchField1 { get; set; }
    public string ResultField1 { get; set; }
    public int ResultField2 { get; set }

    public bool SearchMap(result) { result.ResultField1 == SearchField1 }
}

Then in the APICachingWrapper:
class APICachingWrapper
{
    private ObservableCache _observableCache = new ObservableCache();
    private DbContext _dbcontext;
    private MyAPIWrapper _apiwrapper = new APIWrapper();
    
    abstract bool SearchMap(result) { return true; }

    public ObservableCache getObservableCache() { return _observableCache.Connection();
    }

    public void Search() 
    {
        // Get results from DB cache
        var results = _dbcontext.Set(nameOfmyOverridingClass)
                                .Where(SearchMap());

        // Put results in cache for immediate display
        _observableCache.AddOrUpdate(results);

        // Make an API Call
        _apiwrapper.GetServiceResults(nameOfmyOverridingClass)
                   .Filter(SearchMap())
                   .HandleResults( apiResults => {
                       _observableCache.AddOrUpdate(apiResults);
                       _dbcontext.Set(nameOfmyOverridingClass).Insert(apiResults);
                       });
    }
}

i.e. the common functionality of how to do the caching (and later authentication, authorisation etc.) is in a 'base' class and only things specific to the individual API (field names, search mappings, special functionality) are in the specifically named class.
We've structured our server side code like this and it means that we can implement a 'list' that comes straight from the DB as the 'generic' functionality, we can tweak that so that some result fields are transformed after retrieval from the DB by a custom class based on the default - or we can have a custom class that overrides all the default behaviours and uses a totally different data source e.g. a file on disk - and the consuming code sees them all as type 'list'.
The challenge seems to be that EF Core is written so that the entity 'name' has to be coded into the EF Core calls (and I suspect this is the case for other libraries).
I'm beginning to come to the conclusion (thanks to @Fildor) that my approach is not a C# way of doing things and that either generics or a custom DbContext may be the more C# way of doing it.

protected virtual DbSet<IZymonicFilterResult> DbSet() vs protected override DbSet<CbosFilStockLookupResult> DbSet() - While CbosFilStockLookupResult "is-a" IZymonicFilterResult, DbSet<CbosFilStockLookupResult> and DbSet<IZymonicFilterResult> are still completely unrelated types.

^^ Alas, I think the key to your question is to not use inheritance, but generics. (maybe) I'm still struggling to see where you want to go with this, though.

If it is what I think it is, then I probably just would opt for a bunch of extensionmethods on your db context.

I'll try and edit the question to include a pseudo-code version of what I want to end up with and hopefully that will add more clarity. @Fildor you may well be right about generics; I will do some further reading around them. But extending DBContext may well be much quicker as I think what I want to achieve could well fit the pattern of overriding DBContext methods to make the DB context retrieve from the backing APIs and return an ObservableCache (all whilst using the requested DBSet).

Thanks to @Fildor's pointers I now have a working implementation that is almost exactly what I want.
I have a set of base classes and interfaces that use generics and implement the functionality and API parameters that are common to all of our server's APIs.

    using DynamicData;
    using Refit;
    using System.Linq.Expressions;
    using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
    using System.Text.Json;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    
    namespace ZymonicServices;
    
    
    
    [ZymonicFilterResult]
    public interface IZymonicFilterResult
    {
        public string uid { get; set; }
        public string ToString();
        public DateTime dateUpdated { get; set; }
    }
    public abstract class ZymonicFilterResult : IZymonicFilterResult
    {
        [Key]
        public string uid { get; set; }
        public DateTime dateUpdated
        {
            get
            {
                return _dateUpdated ?? DateTime.Now;
            }
    
            set { this._dateUpdated = value; }
        }
    
        private DateTime? _dateUpdated = null;
    }
    
    public interface IZymonicFilterSearch
    {
        public string search { get; set; }
    }
    public abstract class ZymonicFilterSearch : IZymonicFilterSearch
    {
        public string search { get; set; } = "Refresh Results";
        public string refresh_this_filter_mvs { get; set; } = "true";
    }
    public interface IZymonicFilterApiRequest<TSearch> : IZymonicAPIRequest
    {
        public TSearch searchFields { get; set; }
        public ZymonicAuthentication? Authentication { get; set; }
        public ZymonicAPIHeader ZymonicHeader { get; set; }
    }
    public abstract class ZymonicFilterApiRequest<TSearch> : IZymonicFilterApiRequest<TSearch>
    {
        public ZymonicAuthentication? Authentication { get; set; }
        public ZymonicAPIHeader ZymonicHeader { get; set; }
        // This has to be overridden by a definition which matches the expected JSON
        public abstract TSearch searchFields { get; set; }
    }
    // This is implemented as a class since it doesn't vary between Zymonic Filter APIs.
    public class ZymonicReport<TResult> where TResult : IZymonicFilterResult
    {
        public List<TResult>? result { get; set; }
        public string? signature { get; set; }
    }
    public interface IZymonicFilterResults<TResult> where TResult : class, IZymonicFilterResult
    {
        public List<TResult> GetResults();
    }
    public abstract class ZymonicFilterResults<TResult> : IZymonicFilterResults<TResult> where TResult : class, IZymonicFilterResult
    {
        public List<TResult> GetResults() { return report.result ?? (new List<TResult> { }); }
        public ZymonicReport<TResult>? report { get; set; }
    
    }
    public interface IZymonicFilterApiResponse<TFilterResults, TFilterResult> where TFilterResults : class, IZymonicFilterResults<TFilterResult> where TFilterResult : class, IZymonicFilterResult
    {
        public TFilterResults filterResults { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("session_errors")]
        public List<string>? sessionErrors { get; set; }
    }
    public abstract class ZymonicFilterApiResponse<TFilterResults, TFilterResult> : IZymonicFilterApiResponse<TFilterResults, TFilterResult> where TFilterResults : class, IZymonicFilterResults<TFilterResult> where TFilterResult : class, IZymonicFilterResult 
    {
        // This has to be overridden for the incoming JSON to match the class being deserialised
        public abstract TFilterResults filterResults { get; set; }
    
        [JsonPropertyName("session_errors")]
        public List<string>? sessionErrors { get; set; }
    }
    // TODO Can we do this with fewer generic types?
    public interface IZymonicFilter<TSearch, TSearchAPI, TResult, TFilterResults, TFilterResultsAPI> where TSearch : class, IZymonicFilterSearch, new()
                                         where TSearchAPI : class, IZymonicFilterApiRequest<TSearch>, new()
                                         where TResult : class, IZymonicFilterResult
                                         where TFilterResults : class, IZymonicFilterResults<TResult>
                                         where TFilterResultsAPI : class, IZymonicFilterApiResponse<TFilterResults, TResult>
    {
        public IZymonicFilter<TSearch, TSearchAPI, TResult, TFilterResults, TFilterResultsAPI> ZymonicFilter(IZymonicDbContext context, IZymonicSettings settings, IZymonicAA authService);
        public IObservable<IChangeSet<TResult, string>> Connect();
        public void Search();
        public List<TResult> GetAll();
    
    }
    public abstract class ZymonicFilter<TSearch, TSearchAPI, TResult, TFilterResults, TFilterResultsAPI> where TSearch : class, IZymonicFilterSearch, new()
                                         where TSearchAPI : class, IZymonicFilterApiRequest<TSearch>, new()
                                         where TResult : class, IZymonicFilterResult
                                         where TFilterResults : class, IZymonicFilterResults<TResult>
                                         where TFilterResultsAPI : class, IZymonicFilterApiResponse<TFilterResults, TResult>
    {
        // https://github.com/reactivemarbles/DynamicData?tab=readme-ov-file#the-observable-cachedd
        private readonly SourceCache<TResult, string> _items = new SourceCache<TResult, string>(result => result.uid);
        public SourceCache<TResult, string> results { get { return _items; } }
        public TSearch searchParameters { get; set; } = new TSearch();
    
        private IZymonicDbContext _context;
        private IZymonicSettings _settings;
        private IZymonicAA _authService;
    
        public ZymonicFilter(IZymonicDbContext context, IZymonicSettings settings, IZymonicAA authService)
        {
            _context = context;
            _settings = settings;
            _authService = authService;
        }
    
        // We expose the Connect() since we are interested in a stream of changes.
        // If we have more than one subscriber, and the subscribers are known, 
        // it is recommended you look into the Reactive Extension method Publish().
        public IObservable<IChangeSet<TResult, string>> Connect() => _items.Connect();
        public async Task<bool> Search(bool debugMode)
        {
            // TODO add cancellation token capability
    
            // Trigger the DB search to update the collection
            List<TResult> results = _context.Set<TResult>().Where(whereClause(searchParameters)).ToList();
            _items.Edit(innerCache => { innerCache.AddOrUpdate(results); });
    
            // TODO Refactor this to keep retrieving pages until all done
    
            // TODO Limit cache size and lifetime
    
            // Trigger the API call to update the collection and DB
            List<TResult> apiResults = await GetApiResults(debugMode);
            _items.Edit(innerCache => { innerCache.AddOrUpdate(apiResults); });
    
            // add to DB - This can't be done in parallel because EFCore contexts can be used in parallel
            foreach (var result in apiResults)
            {
                // Update the timestamp
                result.dateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
                var existingResult = _context.Set<TResult>().Find(result.uid);
                if (existingResult == null)
                {
                    // TODO Replace with a better logger?
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Adding {result.uid} to DB");
                    _context.Set<TResult>().Add(result);
                }
                else
                {
                    // TODO Replace with a better logger?
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Updating {result.uid} in DB");
                    _context.Set<TResult>().Entry(existingResult).CurrentValues.SetValues(result);
                }
            }
    
            // TODO Handle removal from cache - challenge is that we're filtering server side and client side 
            // so there is a danger if we compare the local cache to the server results that we remove local 
            // cache entries that don't match rather than ones that don't exist.
            // However, we're implementing the filter both sides and the cache will get repopulated if the
            // API returns it later...
    
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    
            return true;
        }
    
        private async Task<List<TResult>> GetApiResults(bool debugMode)
        {
            // TODO a lot more exception handling
    
            // Set-up the search parameters
            TSearchAPI searchAPI = new TSearchAPI();
            searchAPI.ZymonicHeader = new ZymonicAPIHeader(_settings.SystemName(), "filter", debugMode);
            searchAPI.searchFields = searchParameters;
    
            // Json Options
            JsonSerializerOptions jsonOptions = new()
            {
                DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull,
                NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString
            };
    
            var api = RestService.For<IZymonicFilterApi<TSearch, TSearchAPI, TResult, TFilterResults, TFilterResultsAPI>>(new HttpClient(new ZymonicAuthHandler(_authService, new HttpLoggingHandler()))
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(_settings.BaseUri())
            },
            new RefitSettings
            {
                ContentSerializer = new SystemTextJsonContentSerializer(jsonOptions)
            });
            var apiResponse = await api.FilterResults(searchAPI);
    
            ApiException? apiError = apiResponse.Error;
    
            List<TResult> retrievedResults = new List<TResult>();
    
            if (apiError != null)
            {
                debugInnerException(apiError.InnerException);
            }
            else
            {
    
                // Can do checking of the headers / statuses using apiResponse...
                TFilterResultsAPI apiDecodedResponse = apiResponse.Content;
    
                TFilterResults apiResults = apiDecodedResponse.filterResults;
                retrievedResults = apiResults.GetResults();
    
            }
    
            return retrievedResults;
        }
    
        public List<TResult> GetAll()
        {
            return _context.Set<TResult>().ToList();
        }
    
        // Override to provide the mapping between fields in your TSearch entity and in the TResult entity
        protected Expression<Func<TResult, bool>> whereClause(TSearch search)
        {
            return result => 1 == 1;
        }
        private void debugInnerException(Exception exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
            if (exception.InnerException != null)
            {
                debugInnerException(exception.InnerException);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public interface IZymonicFilterApi<TSearch, TSearchAPI, TResult, TFilterResults, TFilterResultsAPI> where TSearchAPI : class, IZymonicFilterApiRequest<TSearch>
                                                        where TResult : class, IZymonicFilterResult
                                                        where TFilterResults : class, IZymonicFilterResults<TResult>
                                                        where TFilterResultsAPI : class, IZymonicFilterApiResponse<TFilterResults, TResult>
    {
        [Post("")]
        Task<ApiResponse<TFilterResultsAPI>> FilterResults([Body] TSearchAPI search);
    }


I then implement the abstract classes with names and properties (fields) specific to the API as follows:
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using ZymonicServices;


namespace zTSMServices;

public class CbosFilStockLookup : ZymonicFilter<CbosFilStockLookupSearch, CbosFilStockLookupSearchAPI, CbosFilStockLookupResult, CbosFilStockLookupResults<CbosFilStockLookupResult>, CbosFilStockLookupAPIResponse>
{
    public CbosFilStockLookup(IZymonicDbContext context, IZymonicSettings settings, IZymonicAA authService) : base(context, settings, authService)
    {
    }
    protected Expression<Func<CbosFilStockLookupResult, bool>> whereClause(CbosFilStockLookupSearch search) 
    {
        return result => result.cbos_stock_levels_branch_num == search.cbos_stock_levels_branch_num;
    }


}
public class CbosFilStockLookupSearchAPI : ZymonicFilterApiRequest<CbosFilStockLookupSearch>
{
    [JsonPropertyName("cbos_fil_stock_lookup")]
    public override CbosFilStockLookupSearch searchFields { get; set; }
}
public class CbosFilStockLookupAPIResponse : ZymonicFilterApiResponse<CbosFilStockLookupResults<CbosFilStockLookupResult>, CbosFilStockLookupResult>
{
    [JsonPropertyName("cbos_fil_stock_lookup")]
    public override CbosFilStockLookupResults<CbosFilStockLookupResult> filterResults { get; set; }
}

public class CbosFilStockLookupSearch : ZymonicFilterSearch
{
    // The report and search fields are defined by the znames of the contained fields
    // because that is what appears in the API
    [SearchField]
    public string? cbos_stock_levels_branch { get; set; }
    [SearchField]
    public int? cbos_stock_levels_branch_num { get; set; }
    [SearchField]
    public string? cbos_stock_levels_main_barcode { get; set; }
    [SearchField]
    public string? cbos_stock_levels_description { get; set; }
    [SearchField]
    public string? f_catalogue_code_sl { get; set; }

}
public class CbosFilStockLookupResults<TResult> : ZymonicFilterResults<TResult> where TResult : class, IZymonicFilterResult
{
}
[ZymonicFilterResult]
[ZymonicLocalDbSet]
public class CbosFilStockLookupResult : ZymonicFilterResult
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"CbosFilStockLookupResult {uid} at branch {cbos_stock_levels_branch} with main barcode {cbos_stock_levels_main_barcode} has total stock of {cbos_stock_levels_sum_amount} - Updated at: {dateUpdated}";
    }

    [ReportField]
    public string? cbos_stock_levels_branch { get; set; }
    [ReportField]
    public int? cbos_stock_levels_branch_num { get; set; }
    [ReportField]
    public string? cbos_stock_levels_main_barcode { get; set; }
    [ReportField]
    public string? cbos_stock_levels_description { get; set; }
    [ReportField]
    public string? f_catalogue_code_sl { get; set; }
    [ReportField]
    public string? cbos_stock_levels_colour { get; set; }
    [ReportField]
    public string? cbos_stock_levels_sizes { get; set; }
    [ReportField]
    public float? cbos_stock_levels_sum_amount { get; set; }
    // TODO Move this functionality into a base class - but that means yet another Generic type
    [NotMapped]
    private CbosFilStockLookupResultZZid _zzid;
    [NotMapped]
    public CbosFilStockLookupResultZZid ZZid { get { return _zzid; } set { _zzid = value; uid = _zzid.ToString(); } } 
}

public class CbosFilStockLookupResultZZid
{
    public int ztsm_stockid { get; set; }
    public int ztsm_stock_variants_to_levelsstock_holding_id { get; set; }
    public int ztsm_stock_to_process_tjprocessid { get; set; }
    public int ztsm_stock_to_variantsid { get; set; }
    public int cbos_stock_levels_to_branchesid { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{ztsm_stockid}.{ztsm_stock_variants_to_levelsstock_holding_id}.{ztsm_stock_to_process_tjprocessid}.{ztsm_stock_to_variantsid}.{cbos_stock_levels_to_branchesid}";
    }
}

The DBContext implementation only changed a little:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ZymonicServices;

public interface IZymonicDbContext : IDisposable
{
    DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;

    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync();
}

public class ZymonicDbContext : DbContext, IZymonicDbContext
{
    public ZymonicDbContext(DbContextOptions<ZymonicDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        // TODO Need a way to do automatic migrations
        this.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // TODO automatically load assemblies https://www.davidguida.net/how-to-find-all-application-assemblies 

        // https://romiller.com/2012/03/26/dynamically-building-a-model-with-code-first/
        var entityMethod = typeof(ModelBuilder)
    .GetMethods()
    .Where(x => x.Name == "Entity")
    .Where(x => x.IsGenericMethod)
    .FirstOrDefault();

        foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            var entityTypes = assembly
              .GetTypes()
              .Where(t =>
                t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ZymonicLocalDbSetAttribute), inherit: true)
                .Any());

            foreach (var type in entityTypes)
            {
                entityMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type)
                  .Invoke(modelBuilder, new object[] { });
            }
        }
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        return base.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}

This was just to allow me to have an IZymonicDBContext interface that I could implement in different ways in the future if I need to.
The thing I don't like is that I've ended up with an interface / class for the core functionality (the ZymonicFilter) and then a generic for every layer of the incoming and outgong JSON - but I think that the only alternative to this is to implement my own serialisation; I'm not sure whether that would be any better or worse, just different - in some ways a class for each aspect of the JSON is actually quite tidy and readable from a maintainability perspective.
I'm still open to other answers so won't mark this as accepted just yet.
